# C++ general inheritance misunderstanding

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am working on the heritage and polymorphism mechanism in C++, and I have an insolvable problem from my point of view.
Actually I'm guessing, I miss something very simple but I can't figure what it is.
Can someone please help me?

Here is the problem:

I have a base class named `Article` and a derived class named `ArticleEnSolde` and a third class `Caddy` who manage a table of `Article.Article` contains only a `string` and an `int` and `ArticleEnSolde` have a discount system based on percentage.

`Caddy` only contains the `Article` table and have a method called `prixTotal()` which returns the sum of the article price.
But I can't figure how but all the Object are considered as `Article` instead of being considered as ArticleEnSolde`.
And the total sum is incorrect.

Here is Article.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class Article{
private:
    string nom;
    float prix;

public:
    Article(string = "vide",float = -44.6);
    void set_nom(string);
    void set_prix(float);
    string get_nom() const;
    virtual float getPrix() const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Article&);
    virtual ~Article();
};
```

Here is Article.cpp

```
#include "Article.hpp"

Article::Article(string n,float p):nom(n),prix(p){}

void Article::set_nom(string s){
    this->nom = s;
}

void Article::set_prix(float p){
    this->prix = p;
}

string Article::get_nom() const{
    return this->nom;
}

float Article::getPrix() const{
    return this->prix;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o ,Article& a){
    o << "nom article : " << a.get_nom() << " prix : " << a.getPrix();
    return o;
}

Article::~Article(){
    cout << "appel du destructeur d'article " << endl;
}
```

Here is ArticleEnSolde.hpp

```
#include "Article.hpp"
#pragma once

class ArticleEnSolde : public Article{

private:
    float remise;

public:
    ArticleEnSolde(string,float,float);
    float get_remise() const;
    void set_remise(float);
    float getPrix();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,ArticleEnSolde&);
};
```

Here is ArticleEnSolde.cpp

```
#include "ArticleEnSolde.hpp"


ArticleEnSolde::ArticleEnSolde(string s,float f,float i):Article(s,f),remise(i){}

float ArticleEnSolde::get_remise() const{
    return this->remise;
}

void ArticleEnSolde::set_remise(float r){
    this->remise = r;
}

float ArticleEnSolde::getPrix(){
    cout << "ArticleEnSolde " << endl;
    Article * p = this;
    return p->getPrix() * (1 - this->get_remise());
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o ,ArticleEnSolde& a){
    Article * p = &a;
    o <<"nom ArticleEnSolde " << p->get_nom() << " prix : " << p->getPrix() << " remise : " << a.get_remise() << " prix apres reduction " << a.getPrix();
    return o;
}
```

Here is Caddy.hpp

```
#include "Article.hpp"
#include "ArticleEnSolde.hpp"

class Caddy{
private:
    Article ** tableau;
    int index;
    int taille_max;

public:
    Caddy(int);
    Article** get_tab();
    int get_index() const;
    void set_index(int);
    int get_taille_max() const;
    Article* get_article(int);
    void add_article(Article&);
    float prixTotal();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Caddy&);
//  ~Caddy();
};
```

Here is Caddy.cpp

```
#include "Caddy.hpp"

Caddy::Caddy(int i):taille_max(i),index(0){
    tableau = new  Article *[i];
}

Article** Caddy::get_tab(){
    return this->tableau;
}

int Caddy::get_index() const{
    return this->index;
}

void Caddy::set_index(int a){
    this->index = a;
}

int Caddy::get_taille_max() const{
    return this->taille_max;
}

Article* Caddy::get_article(int a){
    return this->tableau[a];
}   

void Caddy::add_article(Article& a){
    if(this->index <this->taille_max){
        cout << "inferieur" << endl;
        this->tableau[this->index++] = &a;
        cout << "ajout reussi" << endl;
        cout << this->index << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "ajout refuse " << endl;
    }
}   

float Caddy::prixTotal(){
    float somme = 0;
    for(int i =0;i<this->get_index();i++){
        cout << this->get_tab()[i]->getPrix() << endl;
    }
    return somme;
}   

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,Caddy& c){

    for(int i = 0 ;i<c.get_index();i++){
        o << "Case " << i <<" " <<  c.get_tab()[i] << endl; 
    }
    return o;
}

/*
    Caddy::~Caddy(){
        cout << "appel du destructeur " << endl;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < this->get_index();i++){
            this->get_tab()[i].~Article();
        }
    }    
*/
```

And finally here is the main code:

```
#include "Article.hpp"
#include "ArticleEnSolde.hpp"
#include "Caddy.hpp"

int main(){
    Article a("a",12);
    ArticleEnSolde b("b",15,0.2);
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    Caddy c(2);
    c.add_article(a);
    c.add_article(b);
    cout << c << endl;
    cout << "prix total : " << c.prixTotal() << endl;
}
```

I want to have at the end "prix total 24" instead of 27 please someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean ["inheritance"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22529/heritage-and-inheritance).

Comment: Yes I didn't Know there was a difference

Comment: Your ArticleEnSolde::getPrix() is kinda of recursive (fortunately it isn't really called)... Why don't you use member veariables instead?

Comment: Correct way would be to call `Article::getPrix()`.

Comment: SO is sometimes a rough place for questions with a lot of code. You probably should have made a bit more effort to reduce the code size, by creating a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which is just one file, and removing the irrelevant article name. Also, you should have used debugger (or debug prints), so your question would have become "Why isn't `ArticleEnSolde::getPrix()` called", which would have been received better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, looks like the problem is, you are not really overriding `getPrix()`.

In `Article`:

```
virtual float getPrix() const;
```

In `ArticleEnSolde`:

```
float getPrix();
```

The difference is, one is `const`, but other is not, so they are not in fact the same method! Make both `const` and that should fix that. Also, remember to add `const` to method definition in the .cpp file, too.

---

And assuming you are using a modern C++ compiler (you should), you could have added C++11 `override` keyword to the overriden `ArticleEnSolde` method:

```
float getPrix() const override;
```

Then you would have gotten compiler error if you missed the `const` (because then it would not have been override).

---

And once you get that fixed, you will need to fix the recursion here:

```
float ArticleEnSolde::getPrix() const {
    cout << "ArticleEnSolde " << endl;
    // pointless: Article * p = this;
    // infinite recursion: return getPrix() * (1 - this->get_remise());
    // Here's how you call superclass method explicitly:
    return Article::getPrix() * (1 - this->get_remise());
}
```

Comment: Even better, add `override` to the overriding declaration.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks for pointing that out, edited.

Comment: thank you everyone